Whiteglass cursor becomes white box In Ubuntu 24.04
in latest ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat the cursor(whiteglass) becomes white square box sometimes, more specifically when you take it to dock or notifications

i have changed the cursor theme to whiteglass from tweaks
These are some more issues I found:

Also, the camera is not being detected
after i grabbed a window, an orange window appeared at top, prompting me to place that window there, its now not going away

I have HP victus, with rizen 5 and radeon. if that helps

Cannot find the cursor in your screenshot

Please ask a different question for the camera.

after i grabbed a window, an orange window appeared at top, prompting me to place that window there, its now not going away Try pushing the window to the right side so that the window is tiled there, and restore it back.

screenshots dont capture cursor, will take a photo
